# Xcode 10 - lipo: can't open input file

Tags: ios, xcode10, ios-frameworks

I recently switched to Xcode 10 and compiled my universal framework. Got this error :

> fatal error: lipo: can't open input file:
>   /Users/testing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-darbltkqlhuhbcfjavjyczodjneq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
>   (No such file or directory)

Getting this second error as well :

> xcodebuild: error: The project
>   '/Users/testing/Documents/workspace/MyFramework/MyFramework.xcodeproj'
>   does not contain a target named ''.

This is the Run Script I have with me :

```
######################
# Options
######################

REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=false

FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


######################
# Build Frameworks
######################

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphonesimulator
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_SIMULATOR_BUILD_DIR}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}"
ARCHS="i386 x86_64" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" $ACTION 2>&1

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos
BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}"
ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" $ACTION 2>&1

######################
# Create directory for universal
######################

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Copy files Framework
######################

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"


######################
# Make an universal binary
######################

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo

# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
                                                                      fi

                                                                      if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then
                                                                      cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo
                                                                      fi

                                                                      ######################
                                                                      # On Release, copy the result to release directory
                                                                      ######################
                                                                      OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"

                                                                      rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
                                                                      mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

                                                                      cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

                                                                      if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
                                                                      open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
                                                                      fi
```

**Note** : Build Active Architecture solution is not what I want.

Comment: what is AN_TARGET? I dont see that variable

Comment: Have you checked your command line tool it is old one or a new one? it should be as per your Xcode like "xcode 10.0(XXXXX)" something like that

Comment: @MohammadSadiq : Thanks for pointing that out. I have replaced it by ${TARGET_NAME} which fixed 2nd issue.

Comment: @iOSTeam : It's the same as Xcode version - 10.1

Comment: @Nitish, I have the same issue, please if you fixed it tell me.

Comment: @Hosny : Check my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, below is the script that worked for me on Xcode 10 :

```
# Typ######################

# Options

######################




REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=false




FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"




SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"




DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"




UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"




FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"







######################

# Build Frameworks

######################




xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1




xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1




######################

# Create directory for universal

######################




rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"




mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"




mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"







######################

# Copy files Framework

######################




cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"







######################

# Make an universal binary

######################




lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo




# For Swift framework, Swiftmodule needs to be copied in the universal framework

if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then

cp -f ${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo

fi



if [ -d "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" ]; then

cp -f ${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/* "${FRAMEWORK}/Modules/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/" | echo

fi




######################

# On Release, copy the result to release directory

######################

OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"




rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"

mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"




cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"




if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then

open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"

fi
```

Comment: now it works thanks but on device only, I get this folder {framework name}-Release-iphoneuniversal, please if you have any advice

Comment: This would work on simulator as well. The file inside this folder is the one you are looking for.

Comment: unfortunately in folder .../{framework-name}.swiftmodule only arm64

Comment: In the project root directory, you'll get an "Output" folder. The file would be there.